# SQL Server- connection forcibly closed during login process

Tags: windows, ssl, sql-server-2005, database-connection, windows-server-2003

The scenario is as follow:

Connection from Windows Server 2003 to SQL Server 2005 works smoothly. Now a new Windows 2012 server which hosts the same .net web application unable to connect to the same SQL Server database, it fails with the following error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]

As it is working fine from Windows 2003, I guess the issue could be one of these:

1. Backward compatibility issue, as the new box is Windows 2012 instead of Windows 2003.
2. Network connectivity issue. However I can confirm the network path is fine as I can telnet port 1433 from the web server to the database server and also part of the error message is

   > A connection was successfully established with the server

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512153/provider-ssl-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install this hotfix for Windows Server 2003. It adds `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA AES128-SHA` and `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA AES256-SHA` cipher suites to Windows Server 2003.

Without these 2 cipher suites added to Windows Server 2003, anything from Windows Server 2008 R2 and above, will not be able to create an SSL connection to Windows Server 2003. This includes SQL Server connections, and any other connections that rely on SSL.

Why? Because Windows Server 2008 R2 and above, have no ciphers that match with what Windows Server 2003 has (the old ciphers have all been removed from new OS's for security reasons); therefore Windows Server 2003 drops the connection because there's no matching cipher available.

Microsoft Hotfix for Windows Server 2003: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/948963

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your SSL and TLS settings(the server only allows 1.2 and your client only supports 1.0.)

Check the following kb page for more inforamtion

[TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server)

Comment: How can i check SSL\TLS setting? BTW, the client is Windows 2008 and the server is Windows 2003 (SQL Server 2005).

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error message:

> Microsoft ODBC Driver {Version number here} for SQL Server : SSL Provider: An existing
> connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I found [this guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ssl-provider-error-0-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-remote-host-error-when-launching-controller-client) and [this post](https://cogknowhow.tm1.dk/archives/2322) to be very helpful on this issue. One suggestion was to "[upgrade your ODBC driver](https://www.reddit.com/r/SQLServer/comments/atwkb6/odbc_driver_tcp_driver_an_existing_connection_was/)", tried that and it didn't work, most of the other discussion is around "Checking you SSL settings" in some shape or form.

What I did to resolve my issue was enable TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 on my SQL Server (in my case 2019) and then on my client systems enable ONLY TLS 1.0 and 1.1 (explicitly disabling TLS 1.2) using the [toolset](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) [linked here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204406/113501). This seems to have resolved my issue.