# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. SSl Provider Error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssl

When I try to connect to the server (SQL Server ,) I get this message.
Is there a way to avoid TLS & SSL when linking

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,
> error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
> host.)

Comment: Disabling security isn't a fix. The error almost certainly complains because you tried to connect from an application that doesn't support TLS1.2, which almost certainly means you're using an unsupported .NET Framework or Windows version. Which versions are you using? The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2 which automatically uses the best TLS version provided by the OS. All supported desktop Windows versions (ie 10 and later) provide TLS 1.2. Other versions require patching

Comment: It makes no sense to try to disable TLS either. All major services, cloud providers *and companies* require TLS1.2 at least. Airlines require it since 2016. PCI-DSS also requires it since 2020. It's way past time to patch

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) and [Protocols in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-#tls-protocol-version-support)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512153/provider-ssl-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by)

Answer (score 1):

You probably getting the error "Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054". Check what ciphers you have enabled - the easiest way to do it is in PowerShell: run PowerShell and execute the following command:

```
foreach ($ CipherSuite in $ (Get-TlsCipherSuite).Name) {"Cipher name:" + $ CipherSuite}
```

The list should look something like this:

```
Cipher name: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  
Cipher name: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  
Cipher name: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  
Cipher name: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA  
Cipher name: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  
Cipher name: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384  
Cipher name: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA384  
Cipher name: TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  
Cipher name: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  
Cipher name: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  
Cipher name: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  
Cipher name: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384  
Cipher name: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384  
Cipher name: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256  
Cipher name: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  
Cipher name: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  
Cipher name: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  
Cipher name: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  
Cipher name: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

If something is missing (probably TLS_DHE ...) create and run this PowerShell script (run it as administrator):

```
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA384"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
pause
```

Restart the computer and check if the connection to SQL Server is working. Let me know if this solution helped.

Tested on Windows 11 22H2 (as client) and SQL Serwer 2005 instaled on old Windows Server 2003.

By the way:
you can DISABLE cipher by name, proper PowerShell command is (run as administraor) for example:

```
Disable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

It works with

```
Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
```