# Cannot connect to server - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms, windows-11

I have updated my PC to Windows 11 Pro ver 22H2, Os build 22621.1
After this update, I cannot connect to SQL Server 2005 from SSMS v.18.4

```
Client OS: Windows 11 Pro ver 22H2, Os build 22621.1
Client SSMS: SSMS v.18.4

Server OS: Windows 2003 5.2.3790 Service Pack 2 Build 3790
SQL Server: SQL Server 2005
```

I have gone thru many web links and came to know it is some thing related to TLS protocol. As we cannot change the protocol, I tried changing this on the client PC ( where the SSMS v18.4 is running). As suggested by Microsoft, I used NARTAC's IIS Crypto 3.3 to set the TLS to 1.0.

But still I'm getting the error.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)
>
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: Use Wireshark to decipher the Client Hello and Server Hello, adn see if there is a cipher mismatch. Presumably the machine running SQL Server does not support an up to date cipher suite. What is the exact build number of Windows on that machine? Are you aware that SQL2005 has now been out of support for 7 years already?

Comment: SSMS 18 doesn't even support 2005. The oldest version that did was the one released with SQL Server 2014. @Charlieface 's implications is tight though; you should long ago moved off 2005 and switched to a recent version.

Comment: @Charlieface Yes. We know, but. We don't have a plan to go with new version as it is tied with an old software.

Comment: Then I guess you are going to have to use an old version of SSMS. Which version of Windows is the server running, exact build number please?

Comment: @Charlieface I have updated the question with versions. It was working before I get update for the client PC.

Comment: Wow Windows Server 2003 went out of support in 2015. I hope you are keeping that on an isolated network. You would need to work out what ciphers are supported and see if you can enable them in W10 using IIS Crypto. I'm not even sure what you expected here, you are connecting to something so out of date that it simply doesn't have any ciphers which aren't cryptographically broken.

Comment: @Charlieface I used IIS Crypto to set the client TLS to 1.0. Unfortunately, I cannot touch the server now. Otherwise, I have to remove the update I received for client PC ( ie. Windows 11 22H2). Because there was no issue with Windows 11 22H1.

Comment: It's not just the TLS version, you need to enable the disabled ciphers. Show us the Wireshark trace as requested, which will tell us what ciphers the server supports.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253658/discussion-between-rauf-and-charlieface).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512153/provider-ssl-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by)